# how to list all CNAMEs of the current server in the bash prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt

I have servers with a generic names (e.g. `eu1.example.com`) which has a set of useful `CNAME` (e.g. `mail.example.com`, `rocket.example.com`). How can I list the `CNAME` in a `bash` prompt, to go from

```
[root@eu1] #
```

to

```
(mail rocket)
[root@eu1] #
```

Comment: try dig, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/dig-command-examples/

Comment: Are `mail.example.com`, `rocket.example.com` pointing to `eu1.example.com`.i.e will a `dig mail.example.com` return `mail.example.com IN CNAME eu1.example.com`. If that is the case, you will not be able to list.